# JavaScript - Scroll with two or more fingers

Tags: javascript, ios, html

I'm working on a Web App with touch support. On IOS I use the "gesturestart" and the "gesturechange" event for touch gesture recognition. But I cant find any documentation for this events. Does anyone know if there is any event for scrolling with two or more fingers?

Comment: Have you looked at [Hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/)?

Comment: Yes I saw it, but I try to find a solution without third-party frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How I did it:

To achieve this **without** using third party frameworks, Use the `event.pointers` property to know how many fingers or pointers are being used: I put it in GestureChange in case someone adds a third finger after starting.

> **Note:** Some sites also show a `event.touches` array, that might be what is required for fingers not mouses

### The code:

```
dom.addEventListener("gesturechange", gestureChange, false);

function gestureChange(e) {
    // use the .length to count the amount of event.pointers
    if(e.pointers.length >= 2){
       // scroll with 2 or more
    }
}
```

### Notes:

The event object returned on gestureChange should look like this: (I used a mouse to generate this so only one touch event and not fingers!)

```
Object { 
   pointers: Array[1], 
   changedPointers: Array[1],
   pointerType: "mouse",
   srcEvent: mousemove,
   isFirst: false,
   isFinal: false,
   eventType: 2,
   center: {x: 1211, y: 332},
   timeStamp: 1435678852765, 
   deltaTime: 22,
   angle:-11.003540851749504 
... more
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But how do I find out if it was an "scroll event"? For pinch zoom I use e.scale, is there something similar for scrolling?

Comment: What you would do there is `on  gestureStart store the x, y coords of the fingers starting spot and `on gestureChange` or `on gestureEnd` subtract that from the new x, y location of the fingers and scroll that much. You can tell direction by whether the new value is negative or positive.

Comment: You probably want to compare that property of the event: center as it has x,y coords and I hope the center of all the fingers on the screen?